# Find and replace words in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, optimization, getelementsbyclassname

I have some HTML that lists lines of words, with each line attached to a class.

I also have a script function that does a global find and replace of the HTML for every occurrence of the word “Five”, replacing it with the word “Zero”.

However, the issue is that I only want to replace “Five” with “Zero” for every occurrence where `class="second"`.

---

**Question**

How do I cycle through each line in the HTML making word replacements for only a specific class, for instance using the `getElementsByClassName()` method?

---

**Code**

Example of the word replacement in action - https://jsfiddle.net/yb0sLhqp/

```
<html>
<body>

<p class="first">One Two Three Four Five</p>
<p class="second">Three Four Five Six Seven</p>
<p class="third">Five Six Seven Eight Nine</p>
<p class="second">Three Four Five Six Seven</p>
<p class="first">One Two Three Four Five</p>
<p class="second">Three Four Five Six Seven</p>
<p class="third">Five Six Seven Eight Nine</p>
<p class="second">Three Four Five Six Seven</p>
<p class="first">One Two Three Four Five</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Replace</button>

<script>

function myFunction() {
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Five/g, 'Zero');
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so select the elements and replace the elements text as you loop over the collection.

Answer (score 2):

So select all the elements with querySelectorAll, loop over, and replace the text.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".second")  // select the elements
    .forEach(elem => // loop over
      elem.textContent = elem.textContent.replace(/Five/g, 'Zero') //replace the text
    )
}

myFunction()

/* without the fat arrow
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".second")  // select the elements
    .forEach(function(elem) { // loop over
      elem.textContent = elem.textContent.replace(/Five/g, 'Zero') //replace the text
    })
}
*/
```

```html
<p class="first">One Two Three Four Five</p>
<p class="second">Three Four Five Six Seven</p>
<p class="third">Five Six Seven Eight Nine</p>
<p class="second">Three Four Five Six Seven</p>
<p class="first">One Two Three Four Five</p>
<p class="second">Three Four Five Six Seven</p>
<p class="third">Five Six Seven Eight Nine</p>
<p class="second">Three Four Five Six Seven</p>
<p class="first">One Two Three Four Five</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Replace</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select element by className and then replace value

```js
function myFunction() {
  let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("second");
  [...elements].forEach(element => {
    element.innerText = element.innerText.replace(/Five/g, 'Zero')
  })
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <p class="first">One Two Three Four Five</p>
  <p class="second">Three Four Five Six Seven</p>
  <p class="third">Five Six Seven Eight Nine</p>
  <p class="second">Three Four Five Six Seven</p>
  <p class="first">One Two Three Four Five</p>
  <p class="second">Three Four Five Six Seven</p>
  <p class="third">Five Six Seven Eight Nine</p>
  <p class="second">Three Four Five Six Seven</p>
  <p class="first">One Two Three Four Five</p>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Replace</button>
</body>
</html>
```